# Parsing a Date and Time string into a ZonedDateTime object

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime, java-time

I am trying to parse a String with a date and time in a known time zone.
The strings have the following format:

```
2019-03-07 00:05:00-05:00
```

I have tried this:

```java
package com.example.test;

import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        ZoneId myTimeZone = ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");

        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXX");

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-03-07 00:05:00-05:00", dateTimeFormatter.withZone(myTimeZone));

        System.out.println(zdt);

    }

}
```

This is the exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-03-07 00:05:00-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at com.example.test.Test.main(Test.java:24)
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am using Java 1.8.0_191.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX`

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Offset X and x: ... Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a
>   colon, such as '+0130'. Three letters outputs the hour and minute,
>   with a colon, such as '+01:30'.

So if your string contains a colon inside timezone, you should use 3 "X-es".

And capital Y means "week-based-year", not a regular one (y).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2019-03-07 00:05:00-05:00".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
```

## Use the offset, Luke

You do not need the time zone. Your string carries an offset-from-UTC of five hours behind UTC. That tells us a specific moment, a point on the timeline.

## ISO 8601

Replace that SPACE in the middle of your input with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601.  The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
String input = "2019-03-07 00:05:00-05:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain this value was intended to a particular time zone, you can apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Be aware that `US/Eastern` is [deprecated as a time zone name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). The modern approach is `Continent/Region`. Perhaps you mean `America/New_York`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Basil, it is really useful to have this second option, I have selected the first one as it identifies how to fix the formatting. I did not know either that US/Eastern was deprecated, good to know it.